# Can this corollary of the intermediate value theorem be used to prove the original theorem in a straightforward way?

Tags: real-analysis

Write $\mathrm{sgn}$ for the [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

In slightly modified form, the intermediate value theorem says:

> **IVT.** Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote a continuous function and suppose $\mathrm{sgn}(f(a)) \neq \mathrm{sgn}(f(b))$ for some pair of real numbers $a < b$ that aren't roots of $f$. Then $f$ has a root in the open interval $(a,b)$.

It has the following important consequence.

> **Corollary.** Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote a continuous function and suppose $x_0$ and $x_1$ are consecutive roots of $f$. Then $\mathrm{sgn}(f)$ is constant on the open interval $(x_0,x_1).$

*Proof.* Suppose $\mathrm{sgn}(f)$ wasn't constant on $(x_0,x_1)$. Then we can find $a,b \in (x_0,x_1)$ such that $f(a) \neq f(b)$. Without loss of generality, assume $a<b$. Then by IVT, $f$ has a root between $a$ and $b$. But this contradicts the assumption that $x_0$ and $x_1$ are consecutive roots.

> **Question.** Can this corollary of the intermediate value theorem be used to prove the original theorem in a straightforward way?

Comment: Your statement of IVT is wrong. Consider $f(x)=x$, $a=0$, $b=1$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen., yes, that was previously a problem, but I've modified it to assume that $a$ and $b$ aren't roots of $f$. That was an edge case I hasn't considered until posting the question.

Comment: Note to self: rethink this idea in terms of "rootless pairs of $f$" when you have more time...

Comment: What does "consecutive root" mean in terms of a function which is 0 on an interval?

Comment: @Joppy, $x_0$ and $x_1$ are consecutive roots of $f$ iff they're roots of $f$ and there does not exist $q \in (x_0,x_1)$ with $f(q) = 0$. So the definition makes sense even if $f$ is zero on some interval. What you're basically observing is that it's not the case that for all $f$-roots $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, if there is an $f$-root strictly greater than $x_0$, then we can necessary find an $f$-root $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_0$ and $x_1$ are consecutive roots of $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That is, assuming that a proof  "in a straightforward way" would not invoke continuity besides when invoking the corollary or amount to essentially redoing a proof of the IVT from scratch.
For example, $f(x)=x$ has a single root, but the corollary cannot make any statement about $f$ because that would require two roots to begin with.

Comment: Hmmm, very good point... :)

Comment: @goblin And even doing something tricky - like replacing $f:x\mapsto x$ with some new $g$, finding an appropriate interval, applying the result to $g$ and that interval, and then translating back to $f$ - wouldn't seem to work (at least I don't see how to do it): $g$ would have to have the property that a *universal* property of $g$ (= sign is constant on the relevant interval) implies an *existential* property of $f$ (= has a zero in the relevant interval) and I don't see how to get this in any way. Obviously that's not a proof, but I do think that's a fundamental obstacle here. (Also, +1.)